# How does Google Play handle discontinuation of an architecture?

Tags: android, android-ndk, google-play

If you have an app on Google Play with a native library, and at some point you publish an updated version where support for an architecture (say, x86) is no more, will Google Play tell x86 users about an upgrade? Will those users still be able to download the older APK, where x86 support was present?

Example: version 1 has a native library built for ARM and for x86. Some people install it from Google Play. Then I, the author, publish version 2 where the said library is built for ARM only. Will existing users of v1 see an app update notification? Will Android/x86 users see the app on Google Play at all (with v1 available for download)?

I don't have a non-ARM Android device with Google Play on it, so I cannot check.

Answer (score 2):

So you have native support libraries for x86 and ARM and you want to discontinue x86 at some point in the future and you want to know what happens when you do?

Under this scenario why would you want to tell the the x86 users to download something they already have? (the older version) or even about the new version (which they could not use)

There is a some what similar [SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846758/android-ndk-and-google-play-filtering) the might help with your question but as I understand it if you require native library support only devices with that architecture will be allowed to down load it, update or not.

Multiple APK support is [documented here](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html)

I guess I am not totally clear what your use case is, the problem might just be that I have been up for 26 hours straight ... ;-)