# Android library .so with x86 architecture missing? (Vuforia)

Tags: android, x86, java-native-interface, arm

I want to integrate the Vuforia Augmented Reality library (jni) in an Android project. The AR is not the core of the application, it's more like a side gadget. But The Vuforia library is not provided for x86 architecture which means x86 Android phones will not be able to download the app.

Is there a way to authorize x86 phone to download the app, and just don't let them play the AR part of the app? That means a way to compile for the x86 arch with a missing library, and also to detect which arch the app is running on?

I know there is not a lot of x86 android phones, and in the end, I might be forced to wait for Vuforia releasing a x86 version of their .so, but I wish to know if there is a way to do what I'm describing here.

Comment: if you can work with NDK just build a library mocking vuforia interface and add that x86 build to your project.

Comment: That's an idea, it seems there is a huge list of .h and methods in the api, looks like a huge work to do this. I guess I would have to create a side project for this.

Comment: Put it under github then you will get some extra reputation for it.

Comment: You should only need to add a single function that returns "no" on x86 and "yes" on ARM, provided you don't call into Vuforia when the function returns no. My understanding is that an attempt to call these functions will result in an exception at runtime, but I'm not entirely sure (especially across different Android versions).

Comment: Interesting, what you say is that I don't need to mock the library? But I'm using this library to compile jni code. When ndk will try to compile jni for x86, I'll get an error, if I provide a library that doesn't mock to original library.

Comment: @tc, thx, look at my answer I solved this problem.

Comment: @tc. This is about app visibility under market as described in post you've linked and ways of possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved the problem quite easily actually. Thx @auselen for helping.

You have a regular Android.mk that fails on x86 architecture because the library (libExternalLibrary.so) you're using is only provided for arm archi.
You want to build a .so (libMyLibraryBasedOnExternalLibrary.so) based on this library.

1) Create 2 dummy .cpp files Dummy0.cpp and Dummy1.cpp exemple Dummy0.cpp looks like this :

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

int dummy0                        =  0;

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Then, edit the Android.mk that build your library and modify it like this :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI), armeabi)


# In this condtion block, we're compiling for arm architecture, and the libExternalLibrary.so is avaialble
# Put every thing the original Android.mk was doing here, importing the prebuilt library, compiling the shared library, etc...
# ...
# ...

else

# In this condtion block, we're not compiling for arm architecture, and the libExternalLibrary.so is not availalble.
# So we create a dummy library instead.

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
# when LOCAL_MODULE equals to ExternalLibrary, this will create a libExternalLibrary.so, which is exactly what we want to do.
LOCAL_MODULE := ExternalLibrary
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := Dummy0.cpp
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
# This will create a libMyLibraryBasedOnExternalLibrary.so
LOCAL_MODULE := MyLibraryBasedOnExternalLibrary
# Don't forget to tell this library is based on ExternalLibrary, otherwise libExternalLibrary.so will not be copied in the libs/x86 directory
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := ExternalLibrary
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := Dummy1.cpp
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

endif
```

Of course, make sure in your code that you never call the library when your app is running on a x86 only device :

```
if ((android.os.Build.CPU_ABI.equalsIgnoreCase("armeabi")) || (android.os.Build.CPU_ABI2.equalsIgnoreCase("armeabi"))) {
    // Good I can launch
    // Note that CPU_ABI2 is api level 8 (v2.2)
    // ...
}
```

Comment: (+1) couldn't you utilize a tool to create mock implementation from available header files?

Answer (score 1):

You can mock `vuforia` by using a tool (like [cmock](https://github.com/ThrowTheSwitch/CMock)?) to create stubs from header files then build it using `NDK` for `x86` and use generated `so` (shared object) in your application.

In that case you should also handle different architectures in your code nicely which probably mean reading up values like [Build.CPU_ABI](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#CPU_ABI)

I would suggest you to put such project under `github` so others can also utilize from it. I am not an expert on licensing but using header files should be fairly legal.

Comment: @jptsetung you know there is a button for thanking ;)